# memory leak about ContentObserver

Tags: android, memory-leaks, mat

I encountered a problem about memory leaks on my android application.

I use startActivity from activity1 to activity2,then go back activity1 by pressing back button.repeat serval time, the adb shell shows that application's RSS is rise and can not drop down.
at last the VM will be shut down.

Then I use MAT find that:

```
Leak Suspects» Leaks» Problem Suspect 1 Description
59 instances of "android.database.ContentObserver$Transport", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 1,569,864 (39.41%) bytes. 

Keywords
android.database.ContentObserver$Transport

 Reference Pattern
Class Name Shallow Heap Retained Heap Percentage 
class android.database.ContentObserver$Transport @ 0x40308cc0 0 0 0.00%
```

but I never use that class.How can I find out the real reason?

Comment: Use LeakCanary to find the where is the leak

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any CursorAdapter? If it is not properly initialized, it could create its on ContentObserver which will produce your leak.

You should use this constructor for the CursorAdapter. The flag 0 will stop it from creating its own ContentObserver.

```
new CursorAdapter(context, cursor, 0)
```